# jQuery syntax error with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

I have the following code which returns a syntax error on line 2 `sales.js:2SyntaxError: Expected token ')'` What's wrong with that?

```
$('<div id="new_contact_dialog"></div>')
.html('<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => 'choose_storage.html.erb') %>')
.dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    modal: true,
    title: 'Add a Contact%>',
    buttons: { 'Create Contact' :  function(){ $(this).find("form").submit(); }, 'Cancel' : function(){ $(this).dialog("close"); } },
    show: "fade",
    hide: "fade",
    width: 420
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `%>` in your `title: 'Add a Contact'` line, which may be making the actual rendered JS screwy, since you're using ERB. I'd recommending inspecting the output of the view in the actual browser; that may help reveal what's going wrong with it.

Other than that, the JS looks like it parses out correctly. I used http://jsbeautifier.org/ to check it out, which makes finding parentheses issues a bit easier to track down.